# Find union and intersection of family or index

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For each $n∈ℕ$, let $βn = \{\ldots, -3n, -2n, -n, 0, n, 2n, 3n,\ldots\}$, and let $β=\{βn:n∈ℕ\}$.

My attempt:

For union, it would be all integers.

As for intersection,

$βn1=\{\ldots, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3,\ldots\}$

$βn2=\{\ldots, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6,\ldots\}$

$βn3=\{\ldots, -9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9,\ldots\}$

etc.

So there would be no intersection, so empty set. Or does $0$ count and so my interception would be $\{0\}$?

Comment: Yes, zero counts. It is a member of each of these sets, isn't it?

Comment: So then my intersection would be {0} since it is the only one that matches across the different sets. Right?

Comment: Yes, the intersection is $\{0\}$.

Comment: @Kazu : Here is the right way to put {curly braces} within MathJax:
$$
\{ a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}
$$
I edited the question accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you, I'm still new and learning the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0$ is in all sets so the set of zero is the intersection of all sets, all members always count.